# Extending 64 bit support to existing iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, 64-bit, cocoapods

I have read [Apple's Guidelines for converting app to 64 bit binary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html) and few other web pages.I am using Xcode 6 and I believe that if Architectures contain "Standard Architecture(armv7,arm64)" and Valid Architectures contain "armv7,armv7s" then it means my app supports 64 bit binaries.

Can someone please confirm if my understanding is correct?

The second issue is that my project contains a number of libraries.I believe that I will have to convert those libraries to 64 bit as well in case the library vendors don't.

In future, I am planning to use cocoa pods, but I believe cocoa pods is not supporting 64 bit binaries right now. Can someone please confirm if my belief is correct? Also what can be done in this case?

Has someone here converted their app to 64 bit using cocoa pods?

Comment: Thank you bilakjakk. I am waiting for few more answers which could give me some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your project as well as** **all the included libraries or frameworks should include arm64 as supported architecture** like below:

Please note that you are missing arm64 in your Valid Architecture menu.

**Valid Architectures :** Specify the architectures you want to build:
amv7 and armv7s are for 32 bit devices.
arm64 is for 64 bit devices

[image]
You may also want to look at this link for more details:

About CocoaPods:
Cocoapods has no relation to 64Bit. As Cocoapods is just a dependency manager and does not gets included in you source code. It works with your build tool chain.

So what you should be worried about is that all the pods you are using should be 64Bit compatible.