# Updating restkit for arm64

Tags: ios, restkit, arm64

I am working on an very old iOS project. I am asked to   [Extending 64 bit support to existing iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447314/extending-64-bit-support-to-existing-ios-app)

Now I took care of project settings, but when I run I am getting: [image]

The problem is that RestKit and other frameworks were installed without using cocoa pods, so my question is: 1) How to get rid of this warning. 
2) Can I delete the RestKit.xcodeproj from project Navigator, Drag and drop a new RestKit.xcodeproj (that I can download from rest kit github page?) and use restkit. If not, what is the way to use update(any) frameworks when not using cocoa pods.

Things I have tried so far: 1) did point (2) mentiond above, it did not work, Tried to use Cocoapods and it did not work. Referred the steps to install rest kit using git submodule mention on readme(restkit github page) it did not work 3)read all restkit and arm64 related threads on stack overflow.

**Please help me update my restkit library for arm 64.**

Thanks for anyone who is going to help me here.

Comment: Can you not just make the same change to the rest kit project as you did to your own so it rebuilds with 64 support?

Comment: Hey, that did not help, gives the same warnings. & may I ask you one question @wain?

Comment: If you update the rest kit project to support 64 then it should compile, if you get the same errors then  you did it wrong. wether it does exactly the correct thing at runtime or has build warnings is a different matter

Comment: does exactly the something.

Comment: did you only update debug and it's building release or something?

Comment: for all, ad hoc, debug, release & distribution: the architecture is same for all which is (Standard architecture (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD))

Comment: how about build active architecture only ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97437/discussion-between-skypirate-and-wain).

Answer (score 0):

1. download new from rest kit github page
2. Open RestKit.xcodeproj in xcode separately, adding or make sure Architectures&Valid Architectures to support arm64. and Build Active Architectures only be set to "No"
3. clean this project and rebuild, if succeed,goto 4
4. Open your proj, delete the old RestKit.xcodeproj from project Navigator, Drag and drop a new RestKit.xcodeproj, you may need to know where the target framework be generated by RestKit.xcodeproj,build
5. if still same error,show me the log